# Por que no puedo acceder a mi variable?

Tags: javascript, html5

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const cx = canvas.getContext('2d');
class Ball{
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.vel=[(Math.random()*5)|0,(Math.random()*5)|0]
    }
    show(context) {
        context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);
    }
}
let ball = new Ball((Math.random() * canvas.width) | 0, (Math.random() * canvas.height) | 0, 10, 10);

console.log(ball);
```

Buenas! Mi problema es que al crear una instancia de 'Ball' con la variable 'ball', puedo acceder a ella mediante console.log(ball), pero al ingresar ball en la consola del navegador, esta devuelve [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
ReferenceError: ball is not defined.

Por que sucede esto?

EDIT:

He probado dejando solo la clase en el archivo js, asi:

```
class Ball {
constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vel = [(Math.random() * 5) | 0, (Math.random() * 5) | 0]
}
show(){
    console.log('good');
}
```

}

pero no cambia nada. Al escribir una linea como la siguiente en la consola:

```
let x = new Ball(10,10)
```

Esta devuelve `ReferenceError: Ball is not defined`

Añado HTML para aquellos que deseen verlo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Brick Blast Ball</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480" style="border: 1px black solid"></canvas>
    <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Saludos podrias hacer algo asi:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
const cx = canvas.getContext('2d');
class Ball{
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.vel=[(Math.random()*5)|0,(Math.random()*5)|0]
    }
    show(context) {
        context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);
    }
}
let ball = new Ball((Math.random() * canvas.width) | 0, (Math.random() * canvas.height) | 0, 10, 10);
recibeBall(ball);
function recibeBall(ball){
alert(ball.x);
}
console.log(ball);
```

```html
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Para mostrar la propiedad **X** de ball en tu funcion update debes pasar dicho parametro **ball** y dentro de tu funcion llamas a ball como gustes como en el ejemplo incluso si pones console.log(ball) todo funcionara bien.

Entonces el error diria yo es porque no recibes ball en tu funcion espero te ayude..!!

Comment: Gracias! te hago otra pregunta continua. por que, al hacer console.log en mi codigo original, este devuelve Object { x: 216, y: 89, vel: (2) […] }, 
pero al hacerlo de la consola una vez cargado el navegador, devuelve un error?

Comment: a que te refieres con : "hacerlo de la consola"

Comment: me refiero al escribir console.log(ball) en la consola del navegador, como se muestra en la imagen

Comment: @taq1408 te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766371/console-access-to-javascript-variables-local-to-the-document-ready-function

Comment: la pregunta marcada como correcta sugiere usar el debugger. Sin embargo, tal función no pausa la ejecución del programa? Además, como implementaría esto a mí codigo?

Comment: Lo que sugiere la respuesta correcta es, que en la pestaña depurado de las herramientas de desarrollo de Firefox debes poner un punto de ruptura dentro de la función donde se declara ball. Esto es por qué una vez que se ejecuta tu código la consola del navegador ya no está en el contexto en el que se creó ball.

Answer (score 0):

Es por la utilización de let de lugar de var, al ser let convierte en anonimo la variable, mientras var termina siendo global entonces al poner var ya podrás modificarlo a través de la consola del navegador

Comment: acabo de probar cambiando let por var, pero el resultado es el mismo

Comment: que extraño a mi si me funciona exactamente como tu lo pusiste, donde estas cargando el javascript?

Comment: estoy usando la version 65.0.1 de 64bits de firefox. es eso a lo que te referias?

Answer (score 0):

La razón es porque el script es un módulo:

```
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

Esto hace que el código no exportado esté encapsulado y no sea global, algo similar a ejecutar el código así:

```js
(function(){
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const cx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  class Ball{
      constructor(x, y) {
          this.x = x;
          this.y = y;
          this.vel=[(Math.random()*5)|0,(Math.random()*5)|0]
      }
      show(context) {
          context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);
      }
  }
  let ball = new Ball((Math.random() * canvas.width) | 0, (Math.random() * canvas.height) | 0, 10, 10);
  ball.show(cx);

  console.log(ball);

})();

console.log(ball);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```